# Multilevel multinominal logistic regression

Tags: repeated-measures, dataset, multilevel-analysis, multinomial-logit

For the analysis of repeated measurements data by developing a multilevel multinominal logistic model, in what format should the data set be prepared? What about any other technical pearls?

Answer (score 1):

In practice it will depend on which software you use to fit the model, but generally data will be in long format, with one row for every subject/unit